# useing mikeal's request when piping something,how to listen events to show progress with a progress-bar

Tags: node.js, request, progress-bar

i am writting a module using mikeal's request to upload and download files 
when piping something,how to listen events to show progress with a progress-bar
please show me some examples
thanks...

Comment: Do you want to show a progress bar in the command line or a progress bar in a website?

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick search on the NPM registry and found [progress](https://npmjs.org/package/progress), a module that shows a progress bar in the command line. It looks nice and it even has an example showing how to use it to show a download progress. I'm reproducing it here:

```
var ProgressBar = require('progress')
  , https = require('https');

var req = https.request({
    host: 'download.github.com'
  , port: 443
  , path: '/visionmedia-node-jscoverage-0d4608a.zip'
});

req.on('response', function(res){
  var len = parseInt(res.headers['content-length'], 10);

  console.log();
  var bar = new ProgressBar('  downloading [:bar] :percent :etas', {
      complete: '='
    , incomplete: ' '
    , width: 20
    , total: len
  });

  res.on('data', function(chunk){
    bar.tick(chunk.length);
  });

  res.on('end', function(){
    console.log('\n');
  });
});

req.end();
```

The code above will generate a progress bar that looks like this:

```
downloading [=====             ] 29% 3.7s​
```

Notice how he checks the `content-length` header to get the length of the file being downloaded and uses that to calculate the completion percentage. It then passes the progress bar the length of each chunk.